# Curves with CSS on DIV

Tags: css

I am trying to make a curve on left and right side of a DIV which will be used as header. So far I have made it look good, however I want to make it more smoother and looks like the image attached. Please check my code on JS Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/shsF2/

```
 .heading-container:before {
    left: -10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 25%;
    transform: skewX(25deg);
  }

  .heading-container:after {
    right: -10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 25% 0;
    transform: skewX(-25deg);
  }
```

But I want it to look like this : http://s9.postimg.org/vo0ru29cf/curvy.jpg

regards

Comment: [Check out this approach](http://css-tricks.com/svg-tabs-using-svg-shape-template/). It's a lot harder/uglier to do with [pure CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363759/how-to-make-rounded-tabs-with-css)

Comment: it's a huge pain to use CSS. I'd recommend just using images.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be a nice challenge, so I gave it a shot in pure CSS.

I'll have to agree with Zach Saucier - It's not pretty

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/EYLfy/)

HTML

```
<div class='topdiv'></div>
<div class='holderdiv1'>
    <div class='leftdiv1'></div>
    <div class='middlediv1'>
        Home -- AboutUs -- Services -- How it Works -- Login
    </div>
    <div class='rightdiv'></div>
</div>
<div class='holderdiv2'>
    <div class='leftdiv2'></div>
        <div class='middlediv2'></div>
</div>
<div class='bottomdiv'></div>
```

...but I learned a couple of CSS tricks.